# Store a table of unknown size in C++

Tags: c++, gcc

I want to store a table in C++(gcc) whose size I dont know before hand it will be decided on realtime which kind of structure to use??

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a vector of the structure you use for a record in the table:

```
vector<MyRecord> v;
```

You add records (objects of type MyRecord) using:

```
v.push_back(record);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean arrays that for most purpose `std::vector` or `std::deque` is what you are looking for.

```
 std::vector<ClassOrTypeYouNeedToStore> v;
 v.push_back(1):
 v.push_back(2):
 v.push_back(3):
 std::cout << "Length of vector " << v.size() << std::endl;
 // Before C++11
 for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++) {
     std::cout << "Next element is " << *it << std::endl;
 }
 // C++11+
 for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++) {
     std::cout << "Next element is " << *it << std::endl;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you need to store and what will vary. If the columns are fixed and of different types and you want to be able to insert and remove rows dynamically, you might want a `std::vector<std::tuple<T,U,V>>` (or instead of a `tuple`, you can use a struct of some sort).

If the columns are fixed but all the same type, give a `std::vector<std::array<T,N>>` a go.

If the number of rows and columns are fixed and of the same type then try `std::array<std::array<T,N>,M>`.

If the number of rows and columns are fixed but each column is of different types, `std::array<std::tuple<T,U,V>,N>` should suit you fine.

If you want the number of columns to also vary, then you'll want the inner type to be a `std::vector` of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

Usually in that case I would use `std::vector`.

```
size_t rsz = 4;
size_t csz = 4;

std::vector<double> table(rsz*csz, 0.0);

for (size_t i = 0; i < rsz; i++) {
  for (size_t j = 0; j < csz; j++) {
    table[i*csz+j] = i * 10 + j;
  }
}
```

I tend to prefer 1D vector and just doing the offset arithmetic myself.  It keeps your helper functions from being over-specialized.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, you can use `vector<vector<CellType>>`, `vector<RowType>`, or, if by "size" you mean "the number of lines" you can use `vector<array<RowSize, CellType>>` (my favourite solution).
[Arrays](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) have the advantage of constant length (performance, memory footprint, memory alignment), and in this solution you get about the same flexibility as in a relational DB.